# Android ART crashing pattern

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, android-runtime

I am testing my app under the **ART** runtime and came up with a curious pattern:

If I install the app while on **Dalvik**, then set ART (developer settings), the phone reboots and takes its time to (compile?) all the applications, **including mine**. This way my app runs flawlessly for a long time.

If on the contrary, I am already with **ART** AND upload a new version with Eclipse (normal development "play project") the app is really unstable and I get Segmentation Faults just after booting like the one enclosed below; the app does boot, but is a matter of seconds that it crashes!

It calls my attention that there's a lot of Dalvik-related functions in the stack trace. Is it possible that the the (debug mode) apps pushed through Eclipse skip a compilation step or something like that?

I am using Android 4.4.4 (Cyanogen/11)

```
/libc    (30412): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000ebe (code=1), thread 30412 (tv.nebular.funq)
I/DEBUG   (  217): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  217): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/jfltexx/jflte:4.2.2/JDQ39/I9505XXUAMDE:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  217): Revision: '11'
I/DEBUG   (  217): pid: 30412, tid: 30412, name: tv.nebular.funq  >>> tv.nebular.funq <<<
I/DEBUG   (  217): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000ebe
I/DEBUG   (  217):     r0 64c0c2b8  r1 00000eb2  r2 00000000  r3 80000000
I/DEBUG   (  217):     r4 0000021b  r5 00000eb2  r6 ffffffff  r7 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  217):     r8 00000000  r9 416fec58  sl 00000000  fp ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  217):     ip be7e9000  sp befe3c08  lr befe3c08  pc 4939f7e4  cpsr 20030030

I/DEBUG   (  217):
I/DEBUG   (  217): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  217):     #00  pc 0042e7e4  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@tv.nebular.funq-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  217):     #01  pc 0001fc04  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  217):
I/DEBUG   (  217): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3bc8  6511da18  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3bcc  6007c4a0  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.art
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3bd0  6511da18  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3bd4  6252671b  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.oat
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3bd8  6007c4a0  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.art
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3be4  625a6205  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.oat
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3be8  600abf28  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.art
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3bec  65124348  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3bf0  65124348  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3bf4  60037220  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.art
I/DEBUG   (  217):          befe3bf8  65124348  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
```

Comment: have you tried this on a stock device or the emulator? I would not be shocked to learn that Cynanogen is broken.

Comment: not yet, will try on genymotion tomorrow (: